# Do copropagating photon pairs exist?

Tags: photons, quantum-spin, pair-production

Countepropagating photon pairs with opposing spin are well known.  Are there physical phenomena that produce copropagating photon pairs with opposing spin?

Wild speculation:  A cooper pair of electrons meets a cooper pair of positrons.

Comment: The polarization of light can be changed by reflection or with thin dielectric films, so it's not clear what you are asking. As soon as one of the photons interacts with matter the original relationship between the polarizations will change, it can even be reversed completely.

Comment: Photon bunching see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect